# Ubuntu 10 or 11 installation on MacMini Server 5,3

Tags: server, mac-mini

I have the latest MacMini Server with the i7 Quad core running OSX lion server.
Has anyone had any luck getting Ubuntu 10 or 11 to run on the latest MacMini's? (5,3)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually gotten around to installing, but I booted from an 11.10 USB flash drive that I made. Most hardware was supported, from the HDMI out to ethernet.
I didn't actually install because I was unable to get WiFi and sound to work. If you are planning to use the machine as a true and pure server, it should be fine (especially headless).

Note: on Mini 5,3 i7 2.0 GHz quad with 16GB RAM